# How can I get the dimensions of a UIImageView as it appears dynamically in any given size class of iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIImageView that only has constraints binding it to the margins and objects above and below it. I have set no fixed height or width constraints, and it visually appears to resize itself properly in the different size classes. But when I try to console log the dimensions of the view as it is in the size class it's currently running in, it always shows the same exact numbers: the height and width it is displayed in the XCode project. I'm using this code and it always logs the same numbers whether I'm running the app on a 4S or 6S+. How can I get the current height of the image view as it is shown in the size class of the device the app is running on?

```
CGRect imageContent = self.tShirtImageView.bounds;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageContent.size.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = imageContent.size.height;
NSLog(@"size of uiimageview: %f, %f", imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Comment: Have you tried `imageContent.bounds.size.height`?

Comment: It depends on where you have put that code. ViewDidLoad? LayoutSubviews? ViewWillAppear? Where are you checking those dimensions? This could be the reason why they're all coming back the same.

Comment: I put it in ViewDidLoad. Where should I put it?

Comment: Try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

the constraint did not layout yet if u ask for width and height in `viewDidLoad`, either put it in `viewDidLayoutSubview` (multiple called) or `viewDidAppear`